# How do i logout the user in the following django code?

Tags: python, django

**What I am trying to do:**

*I am trying to log out the user whenever he/she clicks on the logout button.*

**What problem I am  getting:**

*I get the following problem when I click on logout button:*

[image: Global name error]

**My Code:-**

**article.html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="nav blog-nav">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Library</a>          
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}  
        <a style="float: right;" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'librarysystem:Logout' %}">Logout</a>
        <a style="float: right;" class="nav-link" href="#">{{ request.user.username }}</a> 
        {% if user.UserProfile.avatar == None %}
            <a style="float: right;" class="nav-link" href="#"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="/static/defaultPic/defaultPic.png" class="img-responsive" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail"/></a>
        {% else %}
            <a style="float: right;" class="nav-link" href="#" class="thumbnail"><img class="thumbnail" src="{{ request.user.UserProfile.avatar }}"  class="img-responsive"/></a>     
        {% endif %}    
      {% endif %}           
    </nav>
</div>
```

**login View:**

```
def loginUser(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
       username = request.POST.get('username')
       password = request.POST.get('password')
       data['responseMessage'] = ''
       user = authenticate(username=username,password=password);        
       if user is None:
            data['response'] = False
       else:
            if user.is_active:
                data['responseMessage'] = 'Already logged in.'    
            else:
                login(request,user)
            data['redirectTo'] = "/librarysystem/article/"                    
            data['response'] = True
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**logout View:**

```
def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)      
    template = 'librarysystem/Elib.html'
    return render(request, template)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$',views.registerUser),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="Index"),
    url(r'^validateRegisterForm/$',views.validateRegisterForm),
    url(r'^validateLoginForm/$',views.validateLoginForm),
    url(r'^article/$', views.article, name="Article"),
    url(r'^Login/$',views.loginUser, name="Login"),
    url(r'^Logout/$',views.logoutUser, name="Logout"),
    ]
```

Comment: Why unaccepted my answer? It's the same.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi why did you downvoted my question even though i asked it so nicely ?

Comment: No, I did not downvote it.
I helped you in solving the error. Thats all.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi okay brother i am going to ask another different question if you gave the right answer then i would definitely accept your answer. :)

Comment: You can accept this answer of mine. You can change the accepted answer if you want.

Answer (score 5):

As the error log suggested:

```
global name 'logout' is not defined
```

You need to first import **logout** from django.contrib.auth.
Use this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
```

Like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)      
    template = 'librarysystem/Elib.html'
    return render(request, template)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```